# Select component losing it's css when page is refreshed

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, gatsby, styled-components

I'm building a small website for my company's break room written in React and using Gatsby to translate the app into static content.

I've found that when I refresh the page where my Menu is, the Select elements from Material-UI lose their CSS.
Nothing else in the page loses it's styling, including the `MenuItem` components from Material-UI that I'm using to populate the Select component with options.

I am using `styled-components` to customize the size/position/feel of the Select components, and I've tried removing the styling to see if that was the issue but it didn't affect the behavior.
If 1- I login to the website and 2- navigate to the Menu page the CSS renders properly, **but** if refresh the page it breaks the `Select` component, causing it to lose it's CSS.
+ Also, if I browse directly to the page it breaks the Select component's CSS.

I also noticed some errors in Firefox, when the page is refreshed saying that it was ignoring rulesets due to bad selectors. Errors can be seen at the link below.

**Select component Styled**:

```
const StyledSelect = styled(Select)`
width: 80%;
margin-right: 10%;
margin-left: 10%;
margin-top: 3%;
margin-bottom: 3%;`
```

**Select component used in render()**:

```
<StyledSelect
 multiple={props.isMultiple}
 value={props.value}
 name={props.name}
 onChange={props.handleChange}
>
 {props.items.map(item => (
  <MenuItem key={item._id} value={item}>
   {item.Name}
  </MenuItem>
 ))}
</StyledSelect>
```

I expect the CSS to be persistent even when the page is refreshed, but the actual result is that the Select component breaks after the page is refreshed.

**Gif of Issue**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ORuP.jpg

**Picture of Firefox CSS Warnings**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SjRB.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with SSR, when you reload the page what happen is it gets only the style injected correctly, apparently what you did is install material-ui and expect it to work, what you should do is inject material-ui's style, apparently that needs some configuration with `react-jss`, lately `material-ui` and because of such like issues that everyone complain about they provided examples on how you can solve this issue, one of those examples is gatsby project https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/gatsby , if you do not have time for that you can just install a gatsby plugin https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/ and you won't have this issue again.

Comment: I don't have any ssr though, it's all client side. I wasn't aware that material-ui required ssr. Another thing to note is that other material-ui components that I'm using are rendering succesfully after the refresh. It's just the `Select` component that isn't working. Also it works on the development build just not on the gatsby production build.

Comment: but gatsby uses SSR as far as I know, they are static pages yes but they are server side rendered pages, if it is not the case then Gatsby wouldn't be that famous, without SSR Gatsby will have a big problem with SEO.

Comment: the behavior you describe is commun with ssr

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the advice! I'll give this a shot and follow the material-ui gatsby example and see if I can get this working. I'll be sure to mark this as the answer once I test!

Answer (score 1):

Are there any conditional statements in the render method? I ran into this issue as well, but resolved by swapping out the boolean logic for the Hidden component.

before

```
return(
    {isDeskopDisplay && <MyComponent/>}
)
```

after

```
return(
<Hidden mdUp>
    <MyComponent/>
</Hidden>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to babel file (babel.config.js)

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ["next/babel"],
    plugins: [<br/>
        ["styled-components", { "ssr": true, "displayName": true, "preprocess": 
false }],"inline-react-svg"]};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).